# Powered by: Elementor pro how we can remove in the mail box?

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue I don't want the **Powered by Elementor** text written in the inbox mail message. How can I remove this?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to content in the form.
Click the email dropdown.
Scroll down to Meta Data.
Delete "credit"

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you are using php `mail()` your next step would be to either contact your host or use SMTP to send your site email. [SMTP Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)